# R Shiny - Reset renderText

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

In following code, the goal is to reset the value of textoutput based on the selected value AFTER button1 is clicked:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT, warn.conflicts = FALSE) #shiny also uses: dataTableOutput & renderDataTable
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyBS) #for tooltips on an input or output.
library(htmltools)

ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("lumen"),

                useShinyjs(),

                titlePanel(""),

                selectInput(
                  inputId = "test1",
                  label = strong("pick something"),
                  choices = c("a - button shows", "b - button hidden", "c - button hidden"),
                  selected = "b",
                  selectize = TRUE,
                  width = "175px",
                  multiple = FALSE),

                hidden(actionButton("button1", "Click Me")),

                htmlOutput(outputId = "textoutput")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$textoutput <- renderText({

    if (input$test1 == "a - button shows"){
      print("a")
      shinyjs::show("button1")
      paste("<i><span style='color:blue'>You chose a. You should click the button.</span></i>")
    }

    else if (input$test1 == "b - button hidden"){
      print("b")
      shinyjs::hide("button1")
      paste("<i><span style='color:green'>You chose b. No button.</span></i>")
    }

    else {
      shinyjs::hide("button1")
      print("c")
      paste("<i><span style='color:orange'>The button is hidden.</span></i>")
    }

  })

  observeEvent(input$button1,{
    print(input$test1)
    output$textoutput <- renderText({ paste("<i><span style='color:purple'>You clicked the button.</span></i>")})
    shinyjs::hide("button1")
  })

}

# Create Shiny object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Running the code as is and clicking the button, the text changes to `You clicked the button.`. The part I'm having trouble with is when the value of the drop down changes to "b" or "c" (after clicking the button), the text does not change. I know why it's not changing, but haven't been able to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would want a single `output$textoutput` that is updated based on various changes in inputs.

Perhaps a `reactive` value could contain the message you wish to render. For example:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  msg_txt <- reactiveVal("")

  observe({
    if (input$test1 == "a - button shows"){
      print("a")
      shinyjs::show("button1")
      msg_txt("<i><span style='color:blue'>You chose a. You should click the button.</span></i>")
    }

    else if (input$test1 == "b - button hidden"){
      print("b")
      shinyjs::hide("button1")
      msg_txt("<i><span style='color:green'>You chose b. No button.</span></i>")
    }

    else {
      shinyjs::hide("button1")
      print("c")
      msg_txt("<i><span style='color:orange'>The button is hidden.</span></i>")
    }

  })

  output$textoutput <- renderText({ msg_txt() })

  observeEvent(input$button1,{
    print(input$test1)
    msg_txt("<i><span style='color:purple'>You clicked the button.</span></i>")
    shinyjs::hide("button1")
  })

}
```

Does this have the behavior you were looking for?

Comment: Brilliant! That's exactly the behavior I'm looking for.